# Installing latest stable version of nodejs on centos 7

Tags: centos, centos-7, node.js

I'm trying to install the latest stable version of nodejs on server with centos 7. But after installation, the version remains the same as before:

```
node -v                                                                                                                                              
v6.17.1 

sudo n stable

     install : node-v10.16.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.16.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%                                                                                                 
   installed : v6.17.1
```

I also tried it this way:

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo yum install nodejs

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks                                                                                                                                        
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration                                                                                                             
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration                                                                                                      
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                                                                                                      
 * base: mirror.awanti.com                                                                                                                                                      
 * epel: ru.download.ispsystem.com                                                                                                                                              
 * extras: mirror.awanti.com                                                                                                                                                    
 * ispsystem-5.200: ru.download.ispsystem.com                                                                                                                                   
 * ispsystem-base: ru.download.ispsystem.com                                                                                                                                    
 * updates: centos-mirror.rbc.ru                                                                                                                                                
Package 2:nodejs-6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version                                                                                                 
Nothing to do
```

The version remains 6.17.1 anyway. Is v6.17.1 the same as v10.16.0? If not, how can I install the actual latest stable version of nodejs?

Comment: This may help https://pkgs.org/download/nodejs.